# Add a #/ to the start of the url in a controller redirect in Grails 3.2.3

Tags: grails

I am building a custom angular app in Grails, but sticking as much as possible to the default Grails Controller View behaviour.

What I'm trying to do is: using the scaffolding controller. Get the same behaviour but by ading a #/ to the start of the url. So that after you save a Record, you'd be redirected to:

http://localhost:8080/#/country/show/5

instead of

http://localhost:8080/country/show/5

So that Angular kicks in again. I know this isn't the standard Angular behaviour but I'm trying to use as few angular files as possible since I have very little knowledge in angular.

The default scaffolding redirect is:

redirect country

And I tried using:

redirect base: "#/", country

redirect country, [base: "#/"]

redirect country, base: "#/"

redirect absolute: "#/", country

But they all throw 500 error when called.

This is my current app config in angular:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/:controller/:action",{
        templateUrl:function(params){
            return '/'+params.controller+'/'+params.action;
        }
    })
    .when("/:controller/:action/:param",{
        templateUrl:function(params){
            return '/'+params.controller+'/'+params.action+'/'+params.param;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what's the purpose of that?

Comment: I'm making the views render pieces of html so that they can be used inside a dialog or in the "single" view. Without the /# the controllers show the plain html without any css or angular

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
class SomeController {
    LinkGenerator linkGenerator

    def action() {
        redirect uri: linkGenerator.link(
            controller: 'country', action: 'show', id: 5, base: '/#')
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Given the requirement to support multiple formats, teaching angular to work with "pretty" URLs might be the only way. [Here is an example posting](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) that has the following code:

```
angular.module('scotchy', [])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
                controller : mainController
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
                controller : mainController
            })
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
                controller : mainController
            });

        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Comment: I'm able to hard code it like this  
    redirect(uri: ("#/country/show/" + country.id))
but I was hoping to submit it by sending the object "country" and let the controller chose the default action but with "#/" at the beginning of the URL

Comment: The current app config I'm using works fine. Since I don't have to hard code each URL and I hope to add Spring Security to the project soon. I'm using angular basically to have a single page view and use the urls at the top. I had no choice but to implement a hard coded id since it works fine: redirect action: 'show', id: country.id, base: '/#' but the create method is now giving me the same issue I used to have. Since I need to send the Country object to the edit view, but with the /# at it's beginning

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving up on angular entirely. To show the views inside a dialog I just extract the html segment from the response returned from the server and I get all the default behaviour that Grails includes out of the box.

Since grails is a full stack framework and it's front end is highly customizable. Unless you want to build an entire angular app it's not worth replacing the front end with angular just for it's single view capabilities.

The server responses may be slightly bigger than what I need to show inside a dialog, but it doesn't hurt performance. And the controllers don't know if their views are being rendered inside a dialog or as a full web page, which is what I wanted in the first place.